# Save valid JSON to wordpress post content with slashes (escaped html) through wp_insert_post

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress

I have a JSON string that has html properly striped with slashes.

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "section_name": "Objective",
      "data": "<span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Test</span>",
      "key": "ref"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now i am trying to insert this json string to worpdres post content through wp_insert_post

```
$data = '{"sections":[{"section_name":"Objective","data":"<span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Test</span>","key":"ref"}]}';
    $new = array(
                'post_title'    => $title,
                'post_content'  => $data,
                'post_author'    => $userid,
                'post_status'   => 'pending',
                'post_type' => 'post'
              );
         $id = wp_insert_post($new );
```

Now in the inserted post, I see the slashses are automatically removed.

So when i get the post content, it becomes invalid JSON.

However i could directly save the valid JSON through wordpress admin, or to mysql database through phpmyadmin. It works as expected.

How could i save valid JSON to wordpress post content with slashes (escaped html)

Comment: This might be useful https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/preserve_insert_changeset_post_content/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
data = <<<EOD
{"sections":[{"section_name":"Objective","data":"<span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">Test</span>","key":"ref"}]}
EOD;
    $new = array(
                'post_title'    => $title,
                'post_content'  => $data,
                'post_author'    => $userid,
                'post_status'   => 'pending',
                'post_type' => 'post'
              );
         $id = wp_insert_post($new );
```

This worked.

Comment: Why -1 if the answer is accepted?